# Identifying custom defined object in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check if the object Ball is contained on the `ArrayList` or not. But every time I go through the loop the result gives false answer. But i have already place the object ball in the `ArrayList`. Cant it be done as in:- `someList.contains(new Point(x,y))`

```
public class zbc {

    ArrayList<Balls> balls;
    public boolean somRandomFunction() {

        if (balls.contains(new Ball(i, j, k))) {
            System.out.println("-----------------true------------------");
            break;
        }
    }

}

public class Ball {

    private int row, col;

    // this is actually just a integer value used
    // by game to draw various distinct color
    private int color; 

    public Ball(int row, int col, int color) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int row() {
        return row;
    }

    public int col() {
        return col;
    }

    public int color() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement equals in Ball. Collection.contains uses equals. Test this

```
boolean equals = new Ball(1,1,1).equals(new Ball(1,1,1))
```

it will return false

Comment: didnt help mch i got it another way,
 for (Ball ball : balls) {

                    if (ball.get(i, j) > 0) {
                      
                        sb.append((char) (ball.get(i, j) + 48));
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `equals(Object)` method so Java knows how to match two `Ball` instances.

e.g.,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !o instanceof Ball) {
        return false;
    }
    Ball otherBall = (Ball)o;
    return row == otherBall.row &&
           col == otherBall.col &&
           color == otherBall.color &&
}
```

EDIT:
Also, don't forget that if you implement `equals(Object)`, you should also implement `hashCode()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + row;
    result = prime * result + col;
    result = prime * result + color;
    return result;
}
```